# SDL2 SDL_GetWindowSurface returns surface with unknown pixel format

Tags: window, textures, sdl-2, surface

Not sure why the SDL_GetWindowSurface is returning a surface with an unknown pixel format.

```
Outputs: 
Window pixel format SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888 
Surface pixel format SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UNKNOWN
```

Code follows:

```
char message[256]="";
SDL_Rect rc;
SDL_Window *myWindow;
SDL_Renderer *myRenderer;
SDL_Surface *mySurface;
SDL_Texture *myTexture;

rc.x=100;
rc.y=100;
rc.w=CWState->WindowSize.x;
rc.h=CWState->WindowSize.y;

 //Initialize SDL
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 )
{
    printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    return false;
}

myWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("myWindow", rc.x, rc.y, rc.w, rc.h, 0);
mySurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( myWindow );
myRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(myWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
myTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(myRenderer,SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,rc.w, rc.h);
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(myTexture,SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);

sprintf(message, "Window pixel format %s\n", SDL_GetPixelFormatName(SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat(myWindow)));
puts(message);
sprintf(message, "Surface pixel format %s\n", SDL_GetPixelFormatName(mySurface->format));
puts(message);
```

Also if my Window pixel format is RGB888 should I create the texture with the same format to avoid conversions?

Comment: [You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface)

Comment: is format->format, maybe the pointer got an implicit cast to Uint32? (You should be getting a warning at the very least)

Comment: @Aram : That was it! (mySurface->format)->format.